# How to get class name of the Activity which is bound to a Service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I would like to get the `class name (*.class)` of an `Activity` which is bound to my local `Service`. Is there any native method which i could use to achieve this?

I tried to get that information out of the `Intent` I use to bind to the `Service`. But it seems there is no function in Intents for this.

If I wasn't blind, additionally I would like to know why there's no information about the calling Activity in an Intent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any native method which i could use to achieve this?

No, in large part because the class in question may not exist in your app, and may not even be a class.

You are welcome to package whatever identifying information you would like in the `Intent`, such as via an extra.

Also, if you are allowing third parties to bind to this service, you can use methods like `getCallingUid()` on your `Binder` to find out information regarding the *process* that bound to you.

> additionally I would like to know why there's no information about the calling Activity in an Intent?

Because there is not necessarily a calling `Activity`. The binding engine works with C; C does not have classes, let alone activities.